# Function that creates acronyms from strings

Tags: python

I have got an assignment from school where I have to create a function that receives a string and returns the join of the first letters of each word within the string as an acronym. The return should look like `" the first letter in word number {counter} is {letter}"`, where `{counter}` is the position of the word in the string given and `{letter}` is the first letter of the word. At the end I have to concatenate the following format `" the Acronym for the text given is {acronym}"` where `{acronym}` is the acronym of the text which is the join of the first letters for each word given in the text.

This is what I have done so far:

```
def Acronym_Creator(text:str()):

   text= 'Hello World I Need Help'
   if text != '':
       for word in range(len(text.split())):
          Counter=0
          Counter= Counter+word+1
          print (  'The first letter  in  word number {Counter} is ')
```

So far this is just for counting the position of the word within the text given. I don't know how to concatenate then the word that belongs to that position so I can continue and then create the acronym.

Comment: Can you provide some exmaples: this is input, and this is output?

Comment: Welcome to SO. We usually expect one question per question. Yours looks a little broad/vague. You should [edit] and add a specific question that you would like solved. please read [ask], [mre] and the other links on that page.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
def acronym(text):
    words = text.split(' ')
    acro = ''
    for i in range(len(words)):
        print('The first letter in  word number {} is {}'.format(i+1, words[i]))
        acro += words[i][0].upper()

    print('The acronym is {}'.format(acro))


text = 'Hello World this is some text input'
acronym(text)
```

Output is

```
The first letter in  word number 1 is Hello
The first letter in  word number 2 is world
The first letter in  word number 3 is this
The first letter in  word number 4 is is
The first letter in  word number 5 is some
The first letter in  word number 6 is text
The first letter in  word number 7 is input
The acronym is HWTISTI
```

Answer (score 0):

Here :

```
def acronym(string):
    str_lst = string.split()
    acronym = ""
    for i in str_lst: # go through all the string elements in our list
        acronym += i[0].capitalize() # add the character as 0th position in that string, also you might want to capitalize that letter(if not already). 
    return acronym

String = "Hello World I Need Help"
print(acronym(String))
```

Comment: Yeah, sorry, new to stackoverflow, thanks for pointing out!

Answer (score 0):

I will use regex library for this.

Identification of valid words:

- \b - matches the empty string at the beginning or end of a word
- () - is group you wanna to find
- [A-Za-z] - only letters, ignore expressions starting with invalid characters e.g. numbers
- \w - matches a-z or numeric
- * - zero or more occurences

```py
import re


def acronymizer(string: str):
    words = re.findall(pattern=r'\b([A-Za-z]{1}\w*)', string=string)
    [print(f"The First letter in {w} is {w[0]}") for w in words]
    acronym = ''.join([w[0].upper() for w in words])
    print(f"acronym is: {acronym}")
    return acronym


String = "Hello World I Need Help !"
print(acronymizer(String))
```